# What is the meaning of まっちろけ?

Tags: words, slang

> まっちろけなお弁当になっちゃった。 (context: it's lunch)

or

> どれも、なんかまっちろけでさ。 (context: scene of an accident)

Does it have something to do with 真っ白, masshiro?
I think it may be some sort of obscure slang I don't know about, because I can't find any information on the internet and I don't see how pure white (masshiro) could apply to either of the examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

「まっちろけ」 is indeed a colloquial and/or jocular way of saying 「真{ま}っ白{しろ}」, which means "pure/all white".

「まっちろけなお弁当{べんとう}」 would refer to a bento consisting of rice (which is white) and other things that are mostly very light-colored.  Upon hearing that phrase, most Japanese-speakers would think of a visually unappetizing bento.

Finally, without more context or an explanation of the situation, I could not tell what 「どれも、なんかまっちろけでさ。」 might mean.  It could mean that the speaker has a blurred memory of the accident, but I really should not be speculating.  We do say 「頭の中が真っ白になる」 to mean "My mind went blank."